# How to create subdomain programmatically on plesk centos server

Tags: subdomain, plesk

I am trying to create subdomain on centos plesk server. Visited many blogs but didn't find the perfect solution till yet.

I had also use below command but nothing seems to be work.

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/subdomain -c %subdomain% -www-root %subdomain% -php true -ssi true -d    %domain%
```

Comment: the above command giving me an error: Wrong syntax at -www-root

Answer (score 2):

Finally I had found the solution.

If you have Linux server and plesk is enabled on your server. Than you can use below command to create subdomain from command line.

```
/usr/local/psa/bin/subdomain --create subdomainame -domain domainname -ssi true -php true
```

Comment: Hey Deepak - that's great - works on CentOs - just created subdomain using this line, but is there a way of specifying the directory name as well? By default it simply created folder called site1 and it put it directly under the main domain root folder. Any idea how to specify the exact location and name of the directory?

Comment: If you want to specify a directory for your subdomain, than please use below command. `/usr/local/psa/bin/subdomain --create subdomainame -domain domainname -ssi true -php true -www_root /directoryname`